# How can I do Github-style Markdown rendering from Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, markdown, tilt

TL;DR - how can I use something like `improved_markdown :some_file` to do custom rendering, but still render the layout as usual?

---

Normally, to render Markdown in Sinatra, you'd just do:

```
markdown :some_file
```

But I'd like to add the ability to do "fenced" syntax highlighting, like you can do in Github README files.

````
```ruby
class Foo
  # etc
end
```
````

I've got this partially working.

First, I installed [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) and added a custom rendering class that uses [Pygments.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb/) for syntax highlighting:

```
# create a custom renderer that allows highlighting of code blocks
class HTMLwithPygments < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def block_code(code, language)
    Pygments.highlight(code, lexer: language)
  end
end
```

Then I used it in a route, like this:

````
# Try to load any Markdown file specified in the URL
get '/*' do
  viewname = params[:splat].first

  if File.exist?("views/#{viewname}.md")

    # Uses my custom rendering class
    # The :fenced_code_blocks option means it will take, for example,
    # the word 'ruby' from ```ruby and pass that as the language
    # argument to my block_code method above  
    markdown_renderer = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(HTMLwithPygments, :fenced_code_blocks => true)

    file_contents = File.read("views/#{viewname}.md")
    markdown_renderer.render(file_contents)

  else
    "Nopers, I can't find it."
  end
end
````

This **almost** works. The Markdown is rendered as HTML with additional markup for highlighting purposes.

The only problem is that it does not use my layout; after all, I'm just reading a file and returning the rendered string. The normal `markdown :foo` call would involve Tilt in the process.

Do I have to create a custom Tilt template engine to get that to work, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary options to the `markdown` method (or any of the other rendering methods) and they will be passed on to the Tilt template in question. Tilt’s Redcarpet template looks for any provided `:renderer` option when creating it’s renderer, allowing you to specify a custom one.

You can also specify options that should be applied to all `markdown` calls by passing them as the second argument to `set :markdown, :option => :value`.

It’s not quite as simply as that though, since the current (released) version of Tilt doesn’t correctly detect if you have Redcarpet 2 installed. You can tell it explicitly though:

```
# first ensure we're using the right Redcarpet version
Tilt.register Tilt::RedcarpetTemplate::Redcarpet2, 'markdown', 'mkd', 'md'

# set the appropriate options for markdown
set :markdown, :renderer => HTMLwithPygments,
  :fenced_code_blocks => true, :layout_engine => :haml
```

Now any call to `markdown` should use your custom code for code blocks, and will use `layout.haml` as the layout.

(Disclaimer: I couldn’t get Pygments working (it causes Sinatra to crash every time), but everything else here works (I used a simple custom `block_code` method that just added a message so I could tell it was working).

Comment: Perfect! Not sure if you're getting the same crash I describe in my answer, but I found that it happens if I'm using `rackup config.ru`, but not if I'm running on Passenger.

Comment: @NathanLong I’ve solved my crashing issue – a bit of googling brought up the suggestion that it’s something to do with the initialization of Python in a background thread that causes it, and a call to `Pygments.start` at start up should solve it. Sure enough, after adding that line Pygments is working ok.

Answer (score 0):

### A workaround

I'm currently doing this:

```
if File.exist?("views/#{viewname}.md") 
  CustomMarkdown.render(File.read("views/#{viewname}.md"))
```

Which uses:

```
module CustomMarkdown
  def self.render(markdown_string)
    content = renderer.render(markdown_string)
    layout.render { content }
  end
  def self.renderer
    @markdown_renderer ||= Redcarpet::Markdown.new(HTMLwithPygments, :fenced_code_blocks => true)
  end
  def self.layout
    # Yes, this is hardcoded; in my simple app, I always use this layout.
    Tilt['haml'].new do
      File.read("views/layout.haml")
    end
  end
end
```

This works decently. I have noticed that a fenced block without a keyword, like this:

````
```
  code of unspecified type
```
# vs
```ruby
  explicitly ruby code
```
````

... causes my Sinatra app to crash. I assume this means there's an error in the Python layer, because I can't catch any raised error myself.

**Update**: the crash happens with `rackup config.ru`, but not when I'm using Passenger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zzak's [Glorify](https://github.com/zzak/glorify) gem for that kind of job.

Comment: You can use it if you want syntax highlighted code blocks and nothing else. But despite what it says, it's not a Markdown renderer, but an RDoc renderer, which isn't the same thing at all (it's useless for anything other than documenting Ruby for instance)

Comment: rdoc does mardown too these days but I haven't checked if the gem is capable of that too.

Comment: I recently found this discussion and have to say I am pretty disappointed with glorify at this point. Having troubles setting up github flavored markdown. not sure who is still using RDoc but if thats what you need then use glorify